# Windows 8.1 laptop with eMMC storage restore image to different disk

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning, system-recovery, imaging

I have an ASUS notebook with Windows 8.1 with Bing installed on a 32GB eMMC storage device. Long story short, it is too small to be usable in our scenario.

We have added a 120GB SSD to the device, taken an image of the Windows installation, and would like to restore the image to the new SSD and boot from that.

When booting the machine from a recovery USB key, I can load image restore, and go through the motion. Unfortunately, it does not give an option to select the target device, and as such, simply restores back onto the embedded MMC device.

Is there a way to force the wizard to prompt us for a target device, or do we need to look at third party tools to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, you may need third party tools *and* keep in mind that the ESP is also required, not only the Windows system partition(s).

Comment: But, really, why go to all that trouble when you can simply reinstall? You can download installation media for Windows 7, 8 or 10 directly from Microsoft and, to install, no serial number is required because it's already saved in UEFI.

Comment: Will an 8.1 with Bing license work with Windows 10 though? Thought that had finished now. Is 8.1 with Bing just a marketing thing, and any normal build of 8.1 be ok?

Comment: Yes, it should work and yes, just marketing.

Comment: Might just do that then, depending on how much data and config would need to be transferred between installs. Thanks